# Project "Additional include directory" being ignored

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include

I'm including files from another project in the same solution - it's all worked fine in it's current configuration but I added a new method, and now it can't find any of the include files.

Here's the header file dems_gridmanagement.h:

```
#ifndef dems_gridmanager_h
#define dems_gridmanager_h 1

//## begin module%500EBD96007C.includes preserve=yes
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QTime>
#include <QString>
#include "common_StringUtility.h"
#include "common_SharedMemory.h"
#include "common_QtThread.h"
#include "common_QtThreadable.h"
#include "sma_Maps.h"
#include "dems_Types.h"
...
#include "MQTTs_UDP_Multicast.h"
...
```

And in the additional include directory:

.\GeneratedFiles;$(QTDIR)\include;.\GeneratedFiles\$(Configuration);$(QTDIR)\include\qtmain;$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore;$(QTDIR)\include\QtSql;.\;..\Common;..\DemsCommon;..\Ethernet;..\SMA;..\ModbusTCPIP;..\MQTTs;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Crucially, it includes the "..\SMA", which should allow the "sma_Maps.h" to be found, but I'm getting:

> Error 3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sma_Maps.h': No such file or directory  c:\users...\solution\projects\DemsGridManagement\dems_GridManager.h    33

I tried changing it to:
    #include "../SMA/sma_Maps.h"

which get's rid of the error, but then introduces a new error:

> Error  59  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MQTTs_UDP_Multicast.h': No such file or directory   c:\users...\solution\projects\DemsGridManagement\dems_GridManager.h    39

And also a similar error for an include in a project file that is in a completely different project within the solution, and I haven't even opened or changed anything in.

For some reason, it's like the solution is just selectively ignoring the include directory information with some of the project files, but not others (QT includes work fine, so do the "common" project includes...

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? It was all working fine yesterday!

Edit: Narrowed it down. I added a reference to GridManager from another project:

```
#include "../DemsGridManagement/dems_gridmanager.h"
```

If I remove this, there's no problems in the dems_gridmanager.h file. If it's here, the includes in gridManager go crazy and break.

Answer (score 0):

When including with `#include "filename"` it always search the same directory as the current file. To get the files you have included in "additional include directories" you should include with `#include <filename>`

Comment: But how does it all work without a single include "#include "../DemsGridManagement/dems_gridmanager.h" in a completely different file and project? Also, didn't seem to work with <filename>

Comment: If you are not including `dems_gridmanager.h` anywhere, the preprocessor will not process `dems_gridmanager.h`. Thus, all the errors that might be in `dems_gridmanager.h` will not show up when you compile.

Comment: It is being used though, I'm just trying to reference it somewhere else. Also, didn't seem to work with <filename>

Comment: Do you actually run any code from `dems_gridmanager.h`? Are you able to include other files from the SMA directory (in the same project)? What is you folder structure like. Remember that the path used in "additional include directories" starts at the project file. Not the solution file.

Comment: Just thought of another thing. Does the project causing the problem when you `#include "../DemsGridManagement/dems_gridmanager.h"` have all the same "additional include directories" All projects that include `dems_gridmanager.h` need to be told where the header file dependencies are. Not just the project where `dems_gridmanager.h` actually is.